# git, get rid of local commits / restore branch to upstream

Tags: git

On a branch I did a few(can't exactly remember how many) `git commit` and one `git pull` that resulted in a merge failure.

I realized my local changes/commits were just silly, and can be thrown away.

To do that I did:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D otherbranch
git checkout otherbranch
```

This seems not to be the correct way of undoing things - what would be the best way ?

Comment: After you've deleted `otherbranch` on step #2 you have no point to `checkout` to on step #3

Comment: What's "not correct" about it?  Maybe slightly less than ideal (extra step, slightly-dangerous `-D`) but the obvious alternative, using `git reset --hard`, is "slightly dangerous" too.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not exactly sure what you mean, my otherbranch tracks the upstream `otherbranch`, what I did at #2 & #3 seems to result in just what I wanted.

Comment: @user964970: `git checkout otherbranch` -- what do you think this line means?

Comment: @zerkms in this case, I deleted my local `otherbranch` and so I assumed `git checkout otherbranch` just checked out and switch me over to a local branch based on the upstream `otherbranch` (origin/otherbranch). That's what git told me happened, and from what I can see, I was back at the otherbranch just as it was before I messed up with my local changes. If something other was going on, please do tell

Comment: @user964970: I'm not sure how you can checkout to the branch you just deleted a second ago :-S

Comment: @zerkms If there were no upstream branch also named `otherbranch` I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @user964970: oh, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is blow away your local changes:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always do:

```
git checkout <branch>
git reset --hard <otherbranch>
```

This changes the branch over to exactly match the state of the other branch.

Comment: I've tried a few test cases, with this, it seems perhaps all I needed was to do `git reset --hard origin/otherbranch`

Answer (score 0):

Undoing in git is done using the `reset` command.

Moving back to a known state is typically done using `git reset --hard <SHA>`. The SHA is picked from the commit you want to get back to.

Comment: That was my inital attempt. A `git log`, and a failed attempt to identify the known hash of the upstream.

Comment: `git reflog` can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `git rebase`

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

It allows you to edit your commits as well as remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
git fetch

git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch>
##this will reset your local branch HEAD to TOT commit
```

To avoid creating merge commits while git pull, try :

```
git pull --rebase
```

normal git pull will create a merge commit if you have local unmerged commits.